# proof clarification for convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

$$\text {Prove, that }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{{n}^{3}+5} \text {converges}$$
$$0 < \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{{n}^{3}+5} < \frac{n}{{n}^{3}}$$
$$\sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^{2}}=\left(1 \right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^{2}}
$$and by the limit comparison test
$$\frac{1}{{n}^{2}}$$converges

I attempted the above but it was different from the solution given below.

[image]

Is it equally valid to use $1/n^{2}$ instead of $3/n^2$?

Comment: You are doing fine.

Comment: Simply no,it's not valid to use 1/n^3.think why ?

Comment: Can I assume thus there is no unique $${b}_{n}$$ as long as it resembles $${a}_{n}?$$

Comment: I don't see why. For n>=1, a_n is indeed smaller than b_n.

Comment: do you really mean $n/n^2$ on the second line? if you do, the proof doesn't work.

Comment: It was a typo. I have corrected it(n/n^(3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$0<\dfrac{n+2}{n^3+5}\le\dfrac{2n}{n^3+0}=\dfrac{2}{n^2},\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ Hence you can use [direct comparison test.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDirect_comparison_test&ei=3WgGVaeXE9GQuAS4ioGgCQ&usg=AFQjCNHM98vFiq2Dp05vsrb8FCZRnii1UA&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E&cad=rja)

**OR:**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+2)/(n^3+5)}{1/n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^3+2n^2}{n^3+5}=1$$ hence you can use [limit comparison test.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLimit_comparison_test&ei=FGoGVaWPMcaxuATXzYCgCw&usg=AFQjCNHrjquvb-bAs4moeS7909cR54UReg&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E&cad=rja)

Comment: I gave a green tick because you provided with an alternative.

Comment: Thank you. Also, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2a_n$ is convergent iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent. you can directly use this due to [Cauchy criteria for series.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCauchy%2527s_convergence_test&ei=E24GVfmBB8--uAS9i4LwAQ&usg=AFQjCNHOgOKhOE7mbYUThjpj0bXUyPpLeA&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E&cad=rja)

Comment: Usually, my main concern is finding a "similar" b_n. Could I ask if there are any unique b_n (depending on the nature of the question obviously)?